# Google Auth2.0, what can i do to remove the lock icon in consent screen page?

Tags: google-signin

I would like to know, if I want to obtain Google cloud disk permissions on the page where the user agrees to authorize, how can I avoid the check box. Please refer to the figure below for details. Figure 1 needs to be checked, and Figure 2 does not need to be checked. How to achieve the effect in Figure 2.

[image: Figure 1]
[image: Figure 2]

1. I carefully checked the relevant documents of google auth2.0, and found no relevant content
2. I tried to send an issue to the google community.

Comment: Can you please set your browser to English.  I cant read the scopes so its hard to answer.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I had upload the picture to drive.  You can view it through the link. @LindaLawton-DaImTo    https://drive.google.com/file/d/1wfDfEoCrSW7rNwXSq73OJNb29l08Ei44/view?usp=sharing

Comment: And I want to achieve this effect, when the user is authorized on the consent screen page for the first time.   https://drive.google.com/file/d/1rdu-SQubSi0nFw2O5TtmK2tE2SNUlwbR/view?usp=sharing

Comment: please include details in your question not on google drive  you may want to read [ask]